# SAPUI5 TableSelectDialog multiselect: don't select when clicked on certain column

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog, sapui5, carousel

I'm displaying a carousel in a tableSelectDialog zith multiselect enabled.

The problem is when i click on the carousel navigation arrows the row is also selected when it was unselected or the other way around

```
<TableSelectDialog
    noDataText="No Products Found"
    title="Select Product"
    confirm="handleClose"
    cancel="handleClose"
    items="{
        path : '/Garbage',
        parameters:{expand : 'Pictures'},
        filters : [{
            path : 'AssignedTruck',
            operator: 'EQ',
            value1 : ''
        }]}">
    <ColumnListItem>
        <cells>
            <ObjectIdentifier
                title="{Type}"
                text="{Description}" />
            <Text text="{Location}" />
            <VBox class="sapMLIBNotSelected sapMLIBNotActionable">
                <Carousel pages="{Pictures}" height="5em" loop="true" showPageIndicator="false">
                    <Image src="{PictureBlob}" alt="Example picture of speakers"/>
                </Carousel>
            </VBox>
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
    <columns>
        <Column width="auto">
            <header>
                <Text text="Afval" />
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column width="auto">
            <header>
                <Text text="Locatie" />
            </header>
        </Column>
        <Column width="auto" minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true">
            <header>
                <Text text="" />
            </header>
        </Column>
    </columns>
</TableSelectDialog>
```

The problem is here (within the tableSelectDialog):

```
<Carousel pages="{Pictures}" height="5em" loop="true" showPageIndicator="false">
                <Image src="{PictureBlob}" alt="Example picture of speakers"/>
            </Carousel>
```

Any way disable to un(select) when clicking in the carousel column?

Thanks!